# Combine all rows of a table and add to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have interim results table where each question in a quiz is scored individually. Once that's done, I want to add up certain fields of all rows into a single row and then add the row to a adminresults table. I am able to do this in a two steps but not sure how to combine it into a single query.

This is my code to combine the specific fields from the [interimr table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE0id.jpg):

```
select sum(TotalScore),
       sum(ActualScore),
       GROUP_CONCAT(Scorebreakdown),
       GROUP_CONCAT(Feedback)
From interimr
```

This is my code to enter specific fields into the [adminresults table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yrjh.jpg):

```
INSERT INTO `adminresults`(`TotalScore`, `ActualScore`, `Scorebreakdown`, `Feedback`)
VALUES (50,40, 'First try', 'First try')
```

I have hyperlinked a pics of the structure my tables. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that by "add to" you mean `insert into`.  If you mean "update a single row in", then the syntax is a bit different.

Just use `insert  . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `adminresults`(`TotalScore`, `ActualScore`, `Scorebreakdown`, `Feedback`) 
    select sum(TotalScore), sum(ActualScore), GROUP_CONCAT(Scorebreakdown), GROUP_CONCAT(Feedback)
    From interimr;
```

Note:  you might want additional information such as the date/time of the insertion, but that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks this worked great ! One question however, how would someone go about altering the query so it can add something to adminresults table that it didn't take out from interimresults. For example in php, if i have variable $studentname which i explicitly have and a new column in the adminresults called studentname. I know one way is to use VALUES but can it be combined with the INSERT INTO SELECT format ?

Comment: @slk . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.